# Can anyone fathom a why do this or how it works correctly with this bit of SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've changed the table names but I found this FROM statement in a SP I'm optimizing and I'm wondering the how this could come into being, why would you ever do anything like this, and why does it still work.

```
FROM         tblPezFill pf 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblWolveLocation stfl 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblDuckPez pp 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblChaos o 
INNER JOIN tblBillLeg bi 
INNER JOIN @Facty selFac  
ON bi.WolveId = selFac.WolveId 
ON o.ChaosID = bi.ChaosId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN vwDonald stPres 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblStockChaos so 
            ON stPres.DonaldId = so.DonaldId 
            ON o.StockChaosID = so.StockChaosID 
            ON pp.PezID = o.PezID 
            ON stfl.WolveLocationId = so.WolveLocationId 
            ON pf.PezFillID = o.PezFillID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblCheeseburger p ON bi.CheeseburgerId = p.CheeseburgerId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblChaosCheeseburgerShipped ops ON o.ChaosID = ops.ChaosID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN vwDonald pres ON pp.DonaldId = pres.DonaldId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblDuck ON pp.DuckID = tblDuck.DuckId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN vwDuck ON pp.DuckID = vwDuck.DuckId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblWolveLocation fl ON pf.WolveLocationId = fl.WolveLocationId
```

I've cleaned it up to

```
FROM  tblBillLeg bi 
INNER JOIN @Facty  selFac ON bi.WolveId = selFac.WolveId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblCheeseburger p ON bi.CheeseburgerId = p.CheeseburgerId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblChaos o ON o.ChaosID = bi.ChaosId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblDuckPez pp ON pp.PezID = o.PezID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPezFill pf ON pf.PezFillID = o.PezFillID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblChaosCheeseburgerShipped ops ON o.ChaosID = ops.ChaosID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblStockChaos so ON o.StockChaosID = so.StockChaosID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblWolveLocation stfl ON stfl.WolveLocationId = so.WolveLocationId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN vwDonald stPres ON stPres.DonaldId = so.DonaldId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN vwDonald pres ON pp.DonaldId = pres.DonaldId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblDuck ON pp.DuckID = tblDuck.DuckId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN vwDuck ON pp.DuckID = vwDuck.DuckId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblWolveLocation fl ON pf.WolveLocationId = fl.WolveLocationId
```

Which I believe should be equivalent, I need some testing data.  I just don't get how the first version really worked at all.

Comment: +1: For fugly old code.  I wish SQL Server would do better syntax checking for the `ON` clause.  Is this on 2005, 2008, or 2008 R2?

Comment: +1 This is the white whale of queries

Comment: It was originally on 2000 and I'm doing optimizations for 2005

Comment: [You might want to see the links in my answer here for a fuller explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068301/odd-inner-join-syntax-and-encapsulation/8068447#8068447)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join expressions in SQL are constructive, just like arithmetic expressions.

That is, you can do the following:

```
A JOIN B ON <expr-AB>
```

But you can also substitute another join expression for B:

```
A JOIN (B JOIN C ON <expr-BC>) ON <expr-AB>
```

And the parens may be superfluous if the natural order of precedence would give the same result:

```
A JOIN B JOIN C ON <expr-BC> ON <expr-AB>
```

So the huge fugly query you showed is legal syntax, but it certainly could be more clear.

---

I see the query as a hierarchy like this:

```
so
so --left--> stfl
so --left--> stPres
so --left--> o
             o --inner-> bi
                         bi --inner-> selFac
                         bi --left--> p
             o --left--> pp
                         pp --left--> pres
                         pp --left--> tblDuck
                         pp --left--> vwDuck
             o --left--> pf
                         pf --left--> fl
             o --left--> ops
```

I would rewrite the query like this:

```
FROM tblStockChaos so 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblWolveLocation stfl
  ON so.WolveLocationId = stfl.WolveLocationId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN vwDonald stPres
  ON so.DonaldId = stPres.DonaldId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (tblChaos o 
   INNER JOIN
     (tblBillLeg bi
      INNER JOIN @Facty selFac
        ON bi.WolveId = selFac.WolveId
      LEFT OUTER JOIN tblCheeseburger p
        ON bi.CheeseburgerId = p.CheeseburgerId)
     ON o.ChaosID = bi.ChaosId 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (tblDuckPez pp 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN vwDonald pres
        ON pp.DonaldId = pres.DonaldId 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN tblDuck
        ON pp.DuckID = tblDuck.DuckId 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN vwDuck
        ON pp.DuckID = vwDuck.DuckId)
     ON o.PezID = pp.PezID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPezFill 
     (tblPezFill pf
      LEFT OUTER JOIN tblWolveLocation fl
        ON pf.WolveLocationId = fl.WolveLocationId)
     ON o.PezFillID = pf.PezFillID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN tblChaosCheeseburgerShipped ops 
     ON o.ChaosID = ops.ChaosID
  )
```

---

I can't guarantee I've got all the conditions perfect.  But that's the idea.

Comment: I would have answered very similarly.

Answer (score 2):

My approach was to generate a query plan using table variables and then attempt to re-write the query in the manner it would be compiled.

If you setup with this code:

```
DECLARE @tblPezFill TABLE (PezFillID INT, WolveLocationID INT) -- pf / f1
DECLARE @tblWolveLocation TABLE (WolveLocationID INT) -- stfl
DECLARE @tblDuckPez TABLE (Pezid INT, DonaldID INT, DuckID INT) -- pp
DECLARE @tblChaos TABLE (StockChaosID INT, ChaosID INT, PezID INT, 
  PezFillID INT) -- o
DECLARE @tblBillLeg TABLE (WolveID INT, ChaosID INT, 
  CheeseburgerID INT) -- bi
DECLARE @Facty TABLE (WolveId INT) -- selFac
DECLARE @vwDonald TABLE (DonaldID INT) -- stPres
DECLARE @tblStockChaos TABLE (StockChaosID INT, DonaldID INT, 
  WolveLocationID INT) -- so
DECLARE @tblCheeseburger TABLE (CheeseburgerID INT) -- p
DECLARE @tblChaosCheeseburgerShipped TABLE (ChaosID INT) -- ops
DECLARE @tblDuck TABLE (DuckID INT) -- tblDuck
DECLARE @vwDuck TABLE (DuckID INT) -- vwDuck
```

And then run the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM         @tblPezFill pf 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN @tblWolveLocation stfl 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN @tblDuckPez pp 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN @tblChaos o 
INNER JOIN @tblBillLeg bi 
INNER JOIN @Facty selFac  
ON bi.WolveId = selFac.WolveId 
ON o.ChaosID = bi.ChaosId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN @vwDonald stPres 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN @tblStockChaos so 
            ON stPres.DonaldId = so.DonaldId 
            ON o.StockChaosID = so.StockChaosID 
            ON pp.PezID = o.PezID 
            ON stfl.WolveLocationId = so.WolveLocationId 
            ON pf.PezFillID = o.PezFillID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN @tblCheeseburger p ON bi.CheeseburgerId = p.CheeseburgerId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN @tblChaosCheeseburgerShipped ops ON o.ChaosID = ops.ChaosID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN @vwDonald pres ON pp.DonaldId = pres.DonaldId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN @tblDuck tblDuck ON pp.DuckID = tblDuck.DuckId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN @vwDuck vwDuck ON pp.DuckID = vwDuck.DuckId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN @tblWolveLocation fl ON pf.WolveLocationId = fl.WolveLocationId
```

The beginning of the query plan looks like this:

[image]

The remainder is just a series of left joins so I left them out. My thinking is that if you can duplicate the query plan, you'll know that your new query exactly matches the logic of the original.

Here is what I came up with:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    a2.WolveId,
    a2.ChaosID,
    a2.CheeseburgerID,
    a2.PezFillID,
    a2.PezID,
    a2.StockChaosID,
    a3.DonaldID,
    a3.WolveLocationID
  FROM ( 
    SELECT
      selFac.WolveId,
      a1.ChaosID,
      a1.CheeseburgerID,
      a1.PezFillID,
      a1.PezID,
      a1.StockChaosID
    FROM @Facty selFac 
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT
        bi.ChaosID,
        bi.CheeseburgerID,
        bi.WolveID,
        o.PezFillID,
        o.PezID,
        o.StockChaosID
      FROM @tblBillLeg bi
      INNER JOIN @tblChaos o
        ON bi.ChaosID = o.ChaosID
    ) a1 
      ON selFac.WolveId = a1.WolveID
  ) a2
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
      stPres.DonaldID,
      so.StockChaosID,
      so.WolveLocationID 
    FROM @vwDonald stPres
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @tblStockChaos so 
      ON stPres.DonaldID = so.DonaldID
  ) a3 
    ON a2.StockChaosID = a3.StockChaosID
) a4
LEFT OUTER JOIN @tblDuckPez pp
  ON a4.PezID = pp.Pezid
LEFT OUTER JOIN @tblCheeseburger p 
  ON a4.CheeseburgerID = p.CheeseburgerID
LEFT OUTER JOIN @tblChaosCheeseburgerShipped ops
  ON a4.ChaosID = ops.ChaosID
LEFT OUTER JOIN @vwDonald pres
  ON a4.DonaldID = pres.DonaldID
LEFT OUTER JOIN @tblDuck tblDuck
  ON pp.DuckID = tblDuck.DuckID
LEFT OUTER JOIN @tblWolveLocation fl
  ON a4.WolveLocationID = fl.WolveLocationID
```

The only difference in my execution plan is that a couple fields had an additional step of `compute scalar` and that the final set of left outer joins were not in the exact same order as the original.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought of that.