# Odd INNER JOIN syntax and encapsulation

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I'm usually pretty well versed with JOINS, but this is new.

Suppose three tables (classic case of two tables and a third, linker table):

```
Customer  Product  Transaction
--------  -------  -----------
ID        ID       CustomerID
Name      Desc     ProductID
          Cost     Date
```

(Simplistic on purpose, I can't reproduce the actual structure, it's not my code.)

Normally, to get a table of "who bought what when", I'd do this:

```
SELECT Customer.Name, Product.Desc, Transaction.Date
FROM Product
INNER JOIN Transaction ON Transaction.ProductID = Product.ID
INNER JOIN Customer ON Transaction.CustomerID = Customer.ID
```

But I've been presented with this:

```
SELECT Customer.Name, Product.Desc, Transaction.Date
FROM Product
INNER JOIN ( Transaction
      INNER JOIN Customer ON Transaction.CustomerID = Customer.ID)
ON Transaction.ProductID = Product.ID
```

What's this? Just another syntax, or a performance trick?

(It's on SQLServer, FYI, but presumably that could be applied to others...)

Comment: In MS-Access, each join must be placed in parentheses. In Access, the second query would be correct but the first would generate a syntax error. A migration of code or programming style from Access to SQL Server, perhaps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parentheses do not change the semantics. The position of the `ON` clause controls the order of the logical processing of joins.

**First Query**

```
SELECT Customer.Name,
       Product.Desc,
       Transaction.Date
FROM   Product
       INNER JOIN Transaction
         ON Transaction.ProductID = Product.ID
       INNER JOIN Customer
         ON Transaction.CustomerID = Customer.ID
```

**Second Query**

(Redundant parentheses removed)

```
SELECT Customer.Name,
       Product.Desc,
       Transaction.Date
FROM   Product
       INNER JOIN Transaction
                  INNER JOIN Customer
                    ON Transaction.CustomerID = Customer.ID
         ON Transaction.ProductID = Product.ID
```

So **logically** in your first example the join on `Transaction, Product` happens first then the virtual table resulting from that is joined onto `Customer`, whereas in your second example the join on `Transaction, Customer` happens first then the virtual table resulting from that is joined on to `Product`

This is only logically and as inner joins are both associative and commutative this likely won't make any difference to the execution plan (unless you add `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` to the query) but it can do for outer joins.

This is [covered by Itzik Ben Gan here](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/take-control-joins) but the article has a number of inaccuracies, see the [follow up letter by Lubor Kollar](https://www.itprotoday.com/analytics-and-reporting/letters-february-2004) as well.

Comment: Also, if you examine the query plans you will find they are identical. Ad-hoc client tools are notorious for creating these kinds of queries.